# Understanding pointers with file i/o in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to get a better grasp on pointers.  My class assignment was to create the function for the prototype `void OpenFile(const char *fileName, ifstream &inFile)`.

```
 void OpenFile(const char *fileName, ifstream &inFile) 
 {
  inFile.open(FILENAME, ios_base::in);
  if (!inFile.is_open()) {
   cerr << "Could not open file " << fileName << "\n";
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else {
   cout << "File Open successful";
  }
 }

 //FILENAME is defined as: const char * const FILENAME = "file.txt";

 // function is called in main with:  OpenFile(FILENAME, inFile);
```

I guess what I don't understand is the const char * and the & for the two arguments.  I am guessing that the first argument is a const char * because that's how the assignment defined FILENAME.  But did I have to use a pointer in this case?  Could I have just done

```
    const char FILENAME = "file.txt";
```

and in my OpenFile to have the first parameter just take in a const char.  And then again, why do I need a reference for the second parameter of my function?  Definitely confused on when to use pointers and when to use references.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me say that your function looks a bit strange if you pass in a parameter fileName but then use FILENAME within and fileName is just used for error output. I guess this is not quite correct.

Second, to the const char* issue. char itself is just a char (character) and as such is only one single character. const char FILENAME = "file.txt" would thus not work. Instead you'd need an array of chars (const char FILENAME[] = ...), or as it is done in C use a pointer to the memory location of the text, i.e. char*.

As you seem to use STL, it may be a good idea to just ditch char* and convert to std::string instead.

Third, pointer vs reference is often a matter of taste. At the end they both do the same and within the compiler they are in fact the same. The one difference in use is that you can not pass an empty (null) reference, but you can pass a null pointer. So the recommendation usually is to use references if you really need an object passed, and a pointer for anything that could be optional (in which case you must handle ptr == NULL). Also C strings being char* and other manually allocated memory are usually sent via pointer.

Answer (score 2):

const char* (or char const*) is a pointer to a character (char) that cannot be modified (const). Usually this means a C style string where there is actually an array of characters and the pointer points to the first one, and the after the last character of the string there is a '\0' character that tells the program that the string ends there.

You can do const char foo = 'a', storing a single character in it, but assigning a string into a const char variable is not possible because putting an array (which is what C strings are) into a character variable doesn't make sense.

You could use pointer for the second parameter as well, but using references is better style in C++ when you don't need pointer-specific features. References always point to exactly one element (not an array like pointers can) and they always point somewhere (not nowhere like a NULL pointer does). They are also much easier to use because you can use a reference variable just like it was the object that it points to, where with pointers you need to write (*ptr) to access the pointed-to object.

What you really need is some basic C++ lessons before trying to do the exercise. Read about pointers and references on your course book or some other material. I would link to online material, but I don't know of any sufficiently good one.

Comment: Thanks, I have been reading, just not clear yet.  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

- `fileName` is a traditional C string.  You are passing a string to the function by passing a pointer to the first character of the string.
- `inFile` is a reference to an ifstream variable.  Because it is passed by reference, your function can modify it and return it to the calling program.  In this case, your function opens the file and returns the open file variable.

Answer (score 1):

The `char` type is for single characters (e.g. `char example = 'e'`). So `const char FILENAME = "file.txt"` would not compile.

Here's a [nice tutorial](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cpp/string/array-vs-ptr/) on C strings.